# Sharepoint 2010 HTML5 Compatibility

Tags: html, sharepoint-2010

Is there any way that HTML5 tags like header, article, section, etc.  can work in Sharepoint 2010?  I have found several different responses to this question up to and including "not at all" and "yes, but you need to change your browser support in one of the meta tags from IE8 to IE9."  I've tried the latter solution and it's a no go; When I look in my developer tools it gives me "Empty Text Node" for all my closing HTML5 tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's compatible. But in order to use the technique of HTML5 you also need a browser supporting HTML5 and SharePoint 2010. There is a project on codeplex making a [custom HTML5 master page templates to SharePoint 2010](http://sharepoint2010html5.codeplex.com/) - so yes it's possible. At the same time be aware of that you can't expect fully supported functionality of your SharePoint 2010 farm, but most of it will work.