# Allow multiple files upload in SharePoint 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to build SharePoint custom web part. In that web part I am having only one File Upload control and I need to upload multiple files from the one control.

I tried with different code:

```
<input id="files" type="file" multiple="multiple" />
<input id="files" type="file" AllowMultiple="true" />
<asp:input id="files" type="file" multiple="multiple" />
```

I am not able to select multiple files from the file browser window.

Applications:

SharePoint: version 2010

Browser: IE 11

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thank-you :)

Answer (score 0):

Never developer for Sharepoint, but I used Devexpress controls and know that they can be used in SharePoint WebParts as well. Try their Upload Control, it can select and upload [multiple files](https://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxFileManagerAndUploadDemos/UploadControl/MultiFileSelection.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You may use [drag and drop](http://bitwiser.in/2015/08/08/creating-dropzone-for-drag-drop-file.html) library for this

```
function makeDroppable(element, callback) {

  var input = document.createElement('input');
  input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
  input.setAttribute('multiple', true);
  input.style.display = 'none';

  input.addEventListener('change', triggerCallback);
  element.appendChild(input);

  element.addEventListener('dragover', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    element.classList.add('dragover');
  });

  element.addEventListener('dragleave', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    element.classList.remove('dragover');
  });

  element.addEventListener('drop', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    element.classList.remove('dragover');
    triggerCallback(e);
  });

  element.addEventListener('click', function() {
    input.value = null;
    input.click();
  });

  function triggerCallback(e) {
    var files;
    if(e.dataTransfer) {
      files = e.dataTransfer.files;
    } else if(e.target) {
      files = e.target.files;
    }
    callback.call(null, files);
  }
}

var element = document.querySelector('.droppable');
function callback(files) {
  // Here, we simply log the Array of files to the console.
  console.log(files);
}
makeDroppable(element, callback);
```

Comment: Hi @Lee_SPWX , Thanks for your response, Drag and Drop library is using HTML 5. But SharePoint doesn't support HTML 5

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15938920/sharepoint-2010-html5-compatibility